# Kill a background task in mac

Tags: shell

I have a task(appium server) running in the background. I started this task by running the command `appium &` . After running my tests, i need to kill appium. I tried running `kill <pid_of_appium>` , but the task is not killed immediately. I manually have to press the **Enter** Key to kill it.

I initially thought this was a problem with appium alone, but I tried running several background tasks and all of these tasks are getting killed only after pressing the Enter key. How can i handle this through code as I need to stop the background task programmatically using a shell command

Comment: you mean like this: `bash-3.2$ sleep 100 & /
[1] 16026 /
bash-3.2$ kill 16026 / bash-3.2$ / [1]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 100`? The process is killed right away, you just don't see the notification until you hit enter so it doesn't mess with the command you might be in the middle of typing.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using `kill -9`. It can cause corrupted data and potential problems associated with that. I found this script that should attempt to kill the process with a signal -15, and then with a signal -9 as a last resort.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Getting the PID of the process
 PID=`pid_of_appium`

 # Number of seconds to wait before using "kill -9"
 WAIT_SECONDS=10

# Counter to keep count of how many seconds have passed
  count=0

 while kill $PID > /dev/null
   do
# Wait for one second
sleep 1
# Increment the second counter
((count++))

# Has the process been killed? If so, exit the loop.
if ! ps -p $PID > /dev/null ; then
    break
fi

# Have we exceeded $WAIT_SECONDS? If so, kill the process with "kill-9"
# and exit the loop
if [ $count -gt $WAIT_SECONDS ]; then
    kill -9 $PID
    break
fi
done
  echo "Process has been killed after $count seconds."
```

Answer (score 0):

If a task doesn't respond to a general `kill` command, you can try `kill -9` instead. Adding the `-9` causes the `kill` program to dispatch a much more ruthless assassin to carry out the deed than the normal version does.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `pkill` and `pgrep`:

[pgrep, pkill -- find or signal processes by name](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkill.1.html)

To find the process and print the PID you can use:

```
pgrep -l appium
```

To kill all the processes you can do:

```
pkill appium
```

In case want to send a a `KILL 9` signal you could do this;

```
pkill 9 appium
```